# Annotation of the genomic regions by using R

Tags: r, annotations, regions

I have some genomic regions and their chromosome numbers are known(and which strand they are on), they look like:

```
chr12   32264360        32264363        par_30_2_100_human      4       +
chr20   99393247        99393251        par_30_2_100_human      5       +
chr22   13255328        23255329        par_30_2_100_human      2       +
```

I want to annotate them by using this information but I couldn't convert them to the format that BiomaRt requires ( I am new in R).

Do you maybe know how to annotate them?

Comment: I think it should be 'strand' and not 'stand'. You need to give some more details or link(s) regarding what kind of formatting you want.

Comment: Edited, thank you! About the format, it was asking for ensemble gene ID before beginning and all I have as information is that much that I stated in my question.. Is it possible to use just regions for annotation?